# Proper notation when a function increases over two intervals

Tags: calculus, notation

Let $f(x) = x^3 - 3x$. Then we have $f'(x) = 3(x^2 - 1)$, $f'(x) > 0$ if and only if $x \in (-\infty, -1) \cup (1, \infty)$. Then we can deduce that $f(x)$ is increasing over two intervals $(-\infty, -1)$ and $(1, \infty)$.

However, I have seen other people write "$f(x)$ is increasing over $(-\infty, -1) \cup (1, \infty)$". I believe that this notation is incorrect. $f(x)$ is (strictly) increasing over a set $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ if and only if $f(u) > f(v)$ for any $x, y \in S$ and $x > y$. We have $f(-1.5) = 1.125$ and $f(1.5) = -1.125$. Thus $f(-1.5) > f(1.5)$ while $-1.5 < 1.5$.

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: The usual monotony-definition is only correct for a connected interval. In fact, a better formulation would be : $f$ is increasing on $I$ and on $J$ (where $I$ and $J$ are intervals, where $f$ is increasing).

Comment: A similar problem occurs, if we mix local and global extrema.